# Android - Save User Permission Request (Bluetooth)?

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I have an app that successfully enables the Bluetooth on the device. On create, it asks the user for permission to enable Bluetooth. However, it asks EVERYTIME the app starts. Is there a way to save the user's permission request result so Bluetooth will automatically enable on create?

EDIT: When I load up the BluetoothChat example, it does not ask me for permission, it just goes ahead and enables Bluetooth. How can I get it to do this??

Comment: well, the problem is that it has to ask everytime because the user will need an option on Creation if he wants to uncheck the blutooth once again!?

Comment: @bofredo Im sorry, I dont quite understand what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ApplicationPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref),

Save a flag for permission from user and check that flag on every time application starts.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) to persist the stored data

Comment: That is not the kind of permission he's talking about